# Change DIV text when a button is clicked using JS/JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

Caveat: second time poster, rookie developer. I just finished CodeSchool's "Try JQuery," so now I'm trying to build a little quiz using a mixture of HTML/CSS/JS/JQ. Please excuse any snafus or strayings-from-norms. I hope to bee there soon!

I'm trying to change the text within the class **div.questions** when the **button** is clicked, but nothing's happening. Until now I've only done this on CodeSchool, so this is my first time trying to build it on my own. For all I know, my code is correct but something as fundamental as "script src" is incorrect. I'm currently using the **.text(*new text*)** method, and perhaps I should be using something like **.html(*new text*)**?

Edit: clarification - my issue isn't that this isn't working in JSFiddle. The comments below show why that is, so thanks for that. However, my real issue is that this isn't working while loading the document locally into my browser. I'm using Sublime Edit. Thanks.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ever/jvNf8/

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Tim's JS Quizlet!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>JS and JQuery Quiz</h2>

    <div class="intro">
    Welcome! When the button at the bottom is clicked, the question in the box below 
will change to the next question, and the answer choices below will change to the 
respective choices.
    <br>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="questions">Ready?</div>

    <br>

    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios"> Yes</br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios"> No</br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios"> Wat</br>

    </br>

    <button>Submit</button>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.intro{
font-weight: bold;
width: 50%;
}

div.questions{
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.questions').text("What's your favorite color?");
    });
});
```

Comment: try using `.html("What's your favorite color?")` it will change

Comment: You aren't loading the jQuery library in your fiddle. Change the option on the left (that currently says "Pure JS" to a version of jQuery and it works fine.

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library anywhere? In your fiddle you are not. Including it in the fiddle will in fact change the content of your div. Edit: StephenWidom was first, sorry to repeat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `jQuery` library and change your script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.questions').html("What's your favorite color?");
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jvNf8/8/)

Comment: Thanks for this Rjonacci. A few other people have mentioned that I didn't include the JS library in JFiddle. Note taken, however I'm curious if you're saying that I didn't include the library in my code itself, which was copy/pasted from Sublime Text. So in short, I thought that the following was how you "include the jQuery library", as copied from index.html: <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: make sure you are pointing to the correct URL.. like 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I updated the code in the Head using the following script, and it still doesn't work: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: try this 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> , ..

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Unfortunately it's still not working. Edit: got it working. The problem was that the <script src> was at the bottom of all my code within the <head> tag. I decided to try to put it first (above the reference to my stylesheet and to the actual source of the JS document on my computer), and this worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery from the `Frameworks and Extensions` tab of jsFiddle and it'll work.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvNf8/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
button:action
{
//<how you want it changed here>//
}
```

in your css.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine.

The problem is you're using JSFiddle and you haven't included jQuery. You can do that in the `Frameworks & Extensions` pan on the left.

Answer (score 0):

put the code in your "head" tag:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('button').click(function(){
         $('.questions').html("What's your favorite color?");
       });
    });
 </script>
```

You need to provide the reference of jquery lib, before using jquery functions.

Comment: I was taught to keep my HTML/CSS/JS documents separate.